# Laptop suddenly started randomly turning off and has great trouble starting. Once started, easily shuts down again

Tags: boot, laptop, battery

This is a year-old Dell Latitude 5500. At around 95% battery, it suddenly shut down. Pressing the power button causes the power lights to flash, sometimes for a fraction of a second, sometimes for a few seconds. Sometimes, the keyboard lights turn on, and it boots to Desktop. I would say that it boots around 1 in 20 attempts. The first time this happened, it almost immediately shut down again. The second time, it was able to stay on, until I closed the screen, and it should down again. On one occasion, it showed a "time of day not set error", with several menu options. Another time, it said that "Windows could not boot properly", this time with a graphical menu. What could be the issue?

Comment: Sounds like it's running too hot. Are the fan vents clear and unobstructed? Leave it to cool off, boot and install something like Speccy to check your CPU temperature.

Comment: @spikey_richie I didn't think of that, but it actually seems like the fan is not spinning, as it's completely silent. However, it does not feel hot at all. I would install Speccy if I was able to get it to boot and stay on ;)

Comment: OK, if you can get into the BIOS then set an aggressive fan speed (max 100% all the time if you can) to at least help confirm the problem. Otherwise, you'll need to pop the hood and replace the fan.

Comment: Ok. Interestingly, when I loosened the back screws, it seemed to boot, and stay on for longer. Also, (probably a silly question), why does it not feel hot to touch if it is overheating?

Comment: Because it's the middle of the CPU that's overheating, which doesn't dissipate to the chassis. Once a core exceeds its TDP it'll force a shutdown.

Comment: I waited a while, and it did indeed boot up again. It stayed on for long enough for me to check the CPU temp. A couple minutes after boot, it was around 75C when idling, and steadily rising. I put it right next to an industrial fan, and it cooled to around 60C, and suddenly turned off again. I guess you were correct.